# Programmatically selecting a marker on google map flutter

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

We have to show the marker InfoWindow and increase the size of the marker to show the focus of the highlighted location programmatically. How can we achieve this in flutter google maps?
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQmMS.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can use GoogleMapController to show the info window.

```
googleMapController.showMarkerInfoWindow(markerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi its not possible at the moment but there are issues made for it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29899 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33481.

Answer (score 0):

To select a marker do:

```
maker.onTap();
```

To show marker InfoWindow, do:

```
googleMapController
            .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 45.0))
            .then((_) async {
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
          googleMapController.showMarkerInfoWindow(markerId);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open it outside the *onMapCreated* method after creating the map, you can still call the controller as below. Noted that *_controller* needs to be initialized.

```
final GoogleMapController mapcontroller = await _controller.future;
mapcontroller.showMarkerInfoWindow(MarkerId(MARKER_ID));
```